# A forgetful map which is not injective

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Give an example of an integer $n>1$ and and based space $(X,*)$ such that the forgetful map from $π_n(X,*)$ to $[S^n,X]$ is not injective.

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ For $n>2,π_n(X,*)$ is a group and the forgetful map from the group to the set forgets the base-point i.e. it maps an element $[f]$ to $[f]$ only, so it is an inclusion which is injective, right ?
What am I missing ?

Comment: What does the notation mean? Is it the set of homotopy classes of unbased maps?

Comment: Yes , unbased maps .

Comment: Homotopy classes of based maps need not be the same as those of unbased maps. While there may not be a *based* homotopy $f\simeq g$, there may well be an unbased one. My deleted answer had a mistaken example involving the unit circle.

Comment: Do you know about the action of $\pi_1(X,\ast)$ on $\pi_n(X,\ast)$ and how this relates to $[S^n,X]$?

Comment: Yesterday I know it, it is in Hatcher's book , chapter 4, pg 342 .

Comment: But I don't  know how it relates to $[S^n,X]$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Freely homotopic but not homotopic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128440/freely-homotopic-but-not-homotopic)